# create dictionary from objects and keys arrays in swift 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I have Keys array and Objects array and I want to create a dictionary that each key at index Y in keys array refers to the object at the same index Y in objects array i.e. I want to make code like this but in Swift 2:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:ObjectsArray forKeys:KeysArray];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let keys = [1,2,3,4]
let values = [10, 20, 30, 40]
assert(keys.count == values.count)

var dict:[Int:Int] = [:]
keys.enumerate().forEach { (i) -> () in
    dict[i.element] = values[i.index]
}
print(dict) // [2: 20, 3: 30, 1: 10, 4: 40]
```

or more functional and generic approach

```
func foo<T:Hashable,U>(keys: Array<T>, values: Array<U>)->[T:U]? {
    guard keys.count == values.count else { return nil }
    var dict:[T:U] = [:]
    keys.enumerate().forEach { (i) -> () in
        dict[i.element] = values[i.index]
    }
    return dict
}

let d = foo(["a","b"],values:[1,2])    // ["b": 2, "a": 1]
let dn = foo(["a","b"],values:[1,2,3]) // nil
```

Comment: Why'd you just copy what the guy ~~above~~ below you already had?

Comment: In Swift3, `enumerate` is replaced with `enumerated`. In general, Swift 3 uses present tense verbs to modify objects in place and past tense verbs to return a modified copy -- compare with Python's `sorted` vs `sort`.

Comment: In Swift 3, `index` became `offset`. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic solution

```
func dictionaryFromKeys<K : Hashable, V>(keys:[K], andValues values:[V]) -> Dictionary<K, V>
{
  assert((keys.count == values.count), "number of elements odd")
  var result = Dictionary<K, V>()
  for i in 0..<keys.count {
    result[keys[i]] = values[i]
  }
  return result
}

let keys = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"]
let values = [1, 2, 3, 4]

let dict = dictionaryFromKeys(keys, andValues:values)
print(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    let dict = NSDictionary(objects: <Object_Array>, forKeys: <Key_Array>)

    //Example
    let dict = NSDictionary(objects: ["one","two"], forKeys: ["1","2"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let keyArray = [1,2,3,4]
let objectArray = [10, 20, 30, 40]
let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: objectArray, forKeys: keyArray)
print(dictionary)
```

**Output:-**

```
{
  4 = 40;
  3 = 30;
  1 = 10;
  2 = 20;
}
```